# Store data in the form of file in react.js at front end

Tags: reactjs

Suppose in react application we have some checkboxes with value in react. Upon selecting the checkbox value and clicking on save button. The checkbox value will get stored into a file and it will be also downloadable in the form of text file. Please help with snippet code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    onDownloadClick = () => {
        const content = 'Hello World!!!!!';
        this.refs.link.href = `data:application/octet-stream,${content}`;
        this.refs.link.download = "my-file.txt";
        this.refs.link.click();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a style={{width: "0px", height: "0px", overflow: "hidden"}} ref="link"/>
                <button onClick={this.onDownloadClick}>Download</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```